# Swift Framework inside Cocoapods private pod

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

We are developing an SDK that needs to be compiled in a Cocoa Touch Framework. The project is mainly swift but we are having a bit of c++ so we added objc. Everything works as expected and I can compile the project.
I use an aggregator with a script that builds for arm64 and x86-64.

If I add the .framework directly in the project it works without issues.

Moving on I take the result and with a podspec that contains I try to publish it.

```
s.source_files = 'lib/Classes/**/*', 'libLibrary.framework', 'libLibrary.framework/Headers/*'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'libLibrary.framework'
  s.public_header_files = 'libLibrary.framework/Headers/*'
```

"Lib" being the project name.

Initially we had the same name for the .framework as the main cocoapods library but I changed and wanted to see if this is an issue.

It did not fix the issue.

The problem we are having is that when running the example project that tries to use the framework it gives us the error:
**'Class' is unavailable: cannot find Swift declaration for this class**.

Below the error there is a gray text saying **"Class" has been explicitly marked unavailable here** but taping on that does nothing and simply chimes the error sound. [image: Error we are receiving.]

Did any of you experienced this?

Thank you.

Edit: We do have both arm64 and x86-64 swiftmodule and swiftdoc.

Comment: After investigating further I noticed that the .framework file is not imported in the frameworks folder in project. I have another project that does the same thing only being build in OBJC and there it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue I was having is that I was importing the main library cocoapods library and not the contained framework. Using
`import libLibrary` instead of `import lib` worked.

EDIT: 
To be able to use only `import lib` you need to go in a file inside the cocoapods library that is swift and write `@_exported import libLibrary`. This will cause the generated module to contain `import libLibrary` and not only `import lib.libLibrary`